# How to sort an array by closest with specific value and order by newest?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want sort an array like this:

```
[
  { date: '5/18/2020', number: 22 },
  { date: '5/19/2021', number: 20 },
  { date: '5/18/2021', number: 18 },
  { date: '5/18/2021', number: 23}
]
```

I using this to get closest items with 20:

```
const results = data.sort((a, b) => {
    return Math.abs(20- a.number) - Math.abs(20- b.number);
});
```

The results should like this:

```
[
  { date: '5/19/2021', number: 20 },
  { date: '5/18/2020', number: 22 },
  { date: '5/18/2021', number: 18 },
  { date: '5/18/2021', number: 23}
]
```

But I also want get the results by newest items this:

```
[
  { date: '5/19/2021', number: 20 },
  { date: '5/18/2021', number: 18 },
  { date: '5/18/2020', number: 22 },
  { date: '5/18/2021', number: 23}
]
```

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I don't thinks this question exist already.

Comment: In my case, I want sort by closest value and newest.

Comment: Two conditions (which exactly is not relevant, at least not with these easy ones), which are in fact "multiple conditions" which has already been asked (see dupe targets).